# SSL Error When installing rubygems, unable to install rails gem in windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, rubygems

I am trying to install rails in windows 10. When I attempt to install rails in my gemset, I get the following issue:

```
C:\>gem install rails
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Currently using ruby version.

```
 C:\>ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [i386-mingw32]
```

Gem Vesrion.

```
C:\>gem --version
2.2.3
```

how can I fix these issue help me out from this.

Comment: Do you really want to use Rails under Windows?

Comment: Yes, is there anything problem  developing in windows?

Comment: Lots of problems. Ask anyone here. My suggestion is that you install a Linux virtual machine to do your development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

now I got solution for this issue, using this link http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/#manual-solution-to-ssl-issue

we need to add ***[GlobalSignRootCA.pem](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubygems/rubygems/master/lib/rubygems/ssl_certs/index.rubygems.org/GlobalSignRootCA.pem)*** this certificate in **ssl_certs** folder insted of ***AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem*** 
go through that above link.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely outdated SSL certificates included in installation.
This might help: https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88

Comment: i tried this is not working me, my problem is not resolved